# How can I change the background colour of a specific range of text within a text field? What type of text field can I use within my Web App?

Tags: asp.net

I have a c#.net web app which has multiple asp:textbox fields. I want to be able to change the background colour or text colour of the text within this boxes but only a specific range so for example the first 200 characters are to be red, the remaining characters should be green.

I am aware you can't control the content of a asp:textbox field but I am using ASPNetSpell to perform inline spell checking on all boxes and this renders the field as a asp:textbox.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve this functionality: ability to format partial content within a field and apply a spell checker? I am open to any suggestions.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Laura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the ASPNetSpell textbox is rendered as a div so you should be able to format the text using jQuery. Here is a way you can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#aspnetspellbutton").bind("click", function(eventData) {
        var textfrominputelement = $("#yourinputelementid").text().substr(0, 200);
        textfrominputelement.fontcolor("Red");
    });
});
```

Basically, your binding the aspnetspellbutton click event to the jQuery function and then assigning the first 200 characters of text from the aspnetspell textbox and then changing the color of that text to Red.

This is a terse example. Depending on your requirements it could be a little more complicated. [Script Junkie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ee729206) is a great resource for jQuery if your new to it.

Comment: i agree, some form of javascript is the way to go for this. Be it mootools or as demonstrated above, jQuery.

Comment: I don't think this is correct - the source code which is rendered as a result of using the ASPNetSpell inline spell checker is as follows (there is no DIV tag rendered):
<textarea name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$txt_q1" rows="2" cols="20" id="MainContent_txt_q1">
</textarea>

Comment: It rendered as a div when I viewed the source on their website. You can do the same with the textarea element; substitute the div for the textarea. I'll edit my answer to be more generic.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like a [RichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RichTextBox.aspx) control. [Check this out as well](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/htmlarea.aspx), those could be your solution. Good luck!